# Python Kivy: Как установить шрифт из файла ttf?

Tags: python, шрифты, kivy, ttf

скажите пожалуйста, как Python Kivy зарегистрировать новый рифт из файла ttf, дать ему имя и потом чтобы можно было вызвать его в kv файле через morkup [font=abc]Text[/font]

Answer (score 0):

Переопредели в KV файле правило **Label**:

```
<Label>:
    font_name: "font.ttf"
```

Все. Дальше используй в разметке **Label** как обычно. Шрифт, естественно уже можно не указывать так как ты его уже установил по умолчанию.

Comment: Если я так сделаю, я не смогу использовать одновременно два шрифта. Я просто хочу вставить текст и рядом шрифтовую иконку, чтобы она вела себя так-же как текст